# How do you get a cell value of a selected row in an mx.dataGrid in flash builder

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flash-builder

I thought I could use...

```
studentID = myDataGid.selectedItem.studentID
```

Does not want to work for me. Tracing the expression in debug it is returning   "XMLList (@11e55e8d1)".

The datasource is an XMLListCollection. tracing the expression myDataGid.selectedItem I can see the studentID node and it has a value.

What am I doing wrong?

I see that starting with Flex 4.5, Adobe recommends that we use the spark.components.DataGrid class as an alternative to the mx:dataGrid which I am not at all familiar with or where to start to learn. I have this mx:dataGrid all setup and otherwise working and would prefer not to have to learn something new.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks ok - it returns the part of the xml data that you need. I presume it's a matter of getting the data:

```
studentID = myDataGid.selectedItem.studentID.toXMLString();
```

The above returns the XMLList as a string, but you might need to get that as a Number (depending on the structure of your XML which isn't visible).

Comment: Thanks. Just before coming back to my question I got it working as I thought it should with getselectedItem.studentID. My problem was in fact an issue with the XMLList being used as the datasource. Thanks for your quick reply.